# What floor blocks to use where zombies below CAN see me?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want a zombie spawner to be under my floor, and for the zombies to see me on my floor (their ceiling) and to get them to come after me (via stairs).  The only floor I came up with was:

```
XOXOXOX
XXXXXXX
XOXOXOX
XXXXXXX
XOXOXOX
```

where "X" is an iron bar and "O" is a slab.  It seems to work ok.
Wondering if any other ideas?  I think the middle iron bars aren't transparent to the zombies and obviously the slabs are not transparent.

When the iron bar is next to the slab, it doesn't connect, leaving a gap, and this gap is transparent to the zombies, while still allowing me to walk without falling.

EDIT: by staggering them differently, there is no longer any iron bars that aren't transparent, but instead of each one that wasn't, now I have 2 iron bars that are half transparent, which is a slight improvement as it is now more likely for a zombie to see around that.

```
XOXOXOX
XXXXXXX
OXOXOXO
XXXXXXX
XOXOXOX
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

The easiest block would be glass. You can search on some Minecraft Wikipedia for transparent blocks if you want to choose other than glass.
Edit: there you go https://minecraft.wiki/w/Opacity
Look for them under "Types of transparent blocks" section.

Comment: So glass is transparent to me, but not to the zombie, as it doesn't see me unless I break the glass.

Comment: Indeed, most mobs cannot see through glass, or their dyed variants, with the exception of regular spiders and cave spiders which also have the ability see through solid blocks. Although I hadn't tested it yet, I would imagine that glass panes on the other hand would act similar to iron bars as they have similar collision boxes.